# Cubic function using pow() yielding incorrect values

Tags: c++, math

I want to use a cubic function but I am getting incorrect values when compared to desmos.

I am currently using pow(), but have tried simply multiplying these numbers by themselves but got the same results.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int distance = 1500;
    double aX = (4.8264*pow(10,-8))*distance;
    double bX = 0.000364*distance;
    double cX = -0.8495*distance;
    double rate = -pow(aX,3.0) + pow(bX,2.0) + cX + 592.628;
    cout << rate << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm expecting rate to equal values ranging between -40 and 25, but I'm getting values starting at -681 and decreasing from there (I'm testing int distance at 1500 to 3300). Here is the desmos graph that I am using for the function and expected results: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/g9sdww9c9v.

Comment: You should print out those intermediate values of `aX`, `bX`, etc. to see if they are correct.  That would be the minimum you should have done to whittle the problem down.

Comment: `pow(10,-8)` is better written `1e-8`... and `4.8264*pow(10,-8)` as `4.8264e-8`.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about this post lol. Looks like I just needed to review what coefficients are because I was cubing and squaring those. All working now

Comment: I **hate it** when that happens!